# Media query not working on any iphones

Tags: css, iphone, wordpress, media-queries

I have researched this question all over stackoverflow and I'm still unable to resolve it. Please help if you can :)

I'm using the wordpress theme Hatch which includes a media query that doesn't appear to be affecting any iphones (4 or 5).

Here's the viewport statement in the html that I'm using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I've also tried every variation of a media query that I can think of. Currently, I'm using:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation:portrait) {

    .wrap { 
    max-width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red; 
    }
}
```

I've also tried to no avail:

```
@media only screen and (max-device width: 480px) and (orientation:portrait) {

    .wrap { 
    max-width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red; 
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help with this.

Comment: it could be getting overwritten. do you have a link to the offending website? i could take a quick look

Comment: I could be wrong, but doesn't `initial-scale=1` set it to the normal width of your page (like you would view it on a desktop) and therefore never reach the 480px width?

Comment: Hi Vector - not sure I'm responding the way I'm supposed to, but the site is http://www.lsussman.com/illustration/. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using these

in potrait mode

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) <-- 568px for iphone 5, 480px for iphone 4 -->
and (orientation : portrait) { 
   /* STYLES GO HERE */ 
}
```

in portrait & landscape

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) { 
   /* STYLES GO HERE */
}
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav, thank you for the suggestion but no dice. It's the weirdest thing!

Comment: Just that it won't work I mean. It seems like it should!

Comment: Thanks Howdy_McGee for the suggestion. I tried it and still no dice. I just looked through all my code to see if there were any hanging brackets but everything looks fine. I'm stumped!

Answer (score 0):

Oh man I am a ding-dong! The problem was that there were mismatched {}'s in the CSS code above the media query.

Lesson: When NOTHING is working like it should and it makes NO sense, it's almost always something small somewhere in the code. Well sometimes.

Thanks for the help everybody!